# error sending message to whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am member of a whatsapp group. My name is present in the group member's list. Nobody has removed me. But when I send any message I get the error not a member of this group cannot send any message. Friends also confirm that message has not arrived. Strangely though I can read new posts in the group but cannot see the group icon. I have no clue about how this can happen.

Comment: Try clearing the data for the app (you'll lose your messages) and then log in again.

Comment: Thanks but do I have to clear the data for google drive backup too or just local data?

Comment: @rancho We usually don't provide bugfixes for apps. Only the app developers can do that!

Answer (score 1):

Inform the admin of the group to remove you and add again.
This will works.
And then you will able to send and receive messages.